# Can anyone identify the LaTeX font in this expression?

Tags: fonts, formatting, symbols

I have a document which includes the following expression: [image]

Can anyone identify the font or symbols used for the `D` and `T` characters at all?

I don't have the source LaTeX and need to reproduce this expression exactly.

Comment: `\mathcal{D}` and `\mathsf{T}` no?

Comment: Do you know which package I need to get these symbols?

Comment: No package for `\mathsf{}`, `\mathcal{}` requires the `amssymb` package, although I confess that D looks a teeny tiny bit different to what I'm seeing, there may be a global change

Comment: @MrMorgan: `\usepackage{amsmath}
 Let $\mathcal{D} = \{ \mathsf{T}_1, \mathsf{T}_2, \dots, \mathsf{T}_D \}$ \ldots` produces [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kD45Y.png)...

Comment: Thanks Werner. That works fine. If you can convert your comment to an answer, I will accept it.